# Cache an IEnumerable vs List for lazy initialization

Tags: c#, .net, linq, caching

I have a simple cache class that retrieves and stores any data you pass to it. The only operations that this class has are "Get(string key)" and "Store(string key, object data)". I use this class to store expensive objects and retrieve them quickly.

Imagine I want to store an array. As far as I know, IEnumerable implementations are inherently lazy-instantiated. My question is: if I store an IEnumerable variable to that Cache class (i.e. the resultset of a LINQ query), will this class be stored with all its elements processed or everytime I retrieve that stored IEnumerable I will have to go through all the processing implied to generate that IEnumerable? Should I use the "ToList()" to trigger the initialization?

Notes: I don't have access to the source of this Cache Class, I just know that it stores and retrieves objects.

Comment: What doe this simple cache do that is different from a Dictionary of string, object.

Answer (score 3):

IEnumerable is an interface and not a class. The implemtation behind the interface defines its behaviour.

If you call ToList() on an IEnemerable<> You get a List<>, but also an IEnumerable<> as List implements that interface.

Storing the pointer as an IEnumerable<> and iterating over it is the same as iterating over the list.

If the IEnumerable<> is a result of an iterator, each time the IEnumerable<> is accessed you execute the implementation.

Example:
take the following function:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Generator(int max)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
   {
       yield return someExpensiveFunction();
   }
}
```

using it as

```
var cache = Generator(100);

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
   foreach (var i in cache)
   {
      //ops
   }
}
```

this will evaluate Generator (==IEnumerable<>) twice.

```
var cache = Generator(100).ToList();

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++
{
   foreach(var i in cache)
   {
      //ops
   }
}
```

this will evaluate Generator (==IENumerable<>) only once.

I.E. Caching a IEnumerable<> is not expensive if you make it 'concrete' by calling ToArray(), ToList() etc on it.

Dome additional guidance. If you convert your enumerable to lists and store them it's good practice to declare the storing variable as a list. This to document it's storage model to your users and/or co-workers. 
The result from a function or property on a public class/interface should be Collection

```
class X
{
   private List<int> _cache;

   public void UpdateCache(IEnumerable<int> items)
   {
     _cache = items.ToList();
   }

   public ICollection<T> Cache
   {
      get{ return _cache; }
   }

   //even better
   public ReadOnlyCollection<T> Items
   {
      get { return new ReadonlyCollection(_cache); }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, that means that calling Generator without the .List(), you call the loop in Generator function twice? I mean, for your example, there would be 200 iterations in total for the Generator function? If you made the external loop "for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)", there would be 400 iterations in total? I thought the yield return deferred execution so you don't perform unnecessary operations, if I'm not mistaken, and then everything would be stored and processed in that variable.